# ASP Web Forms : Text box is retaining old values in post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have 2 `text boxes` with `compare validator` controls . But at postback ,the `textbox` values are appended by comma. And on edit mode new value is appended by comma followed by previous value.

Create Mode
[image]

Edit Mode 
[image: At Edit mode]

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            lblClientName.Text = "" + Request.QueryString["clientname"];
            BindAddressSheet();           
            string addrShtId = "" + Request.QueryString["addrshtid"];
            hdnAddrSheetId.Value = addrShtId;               
            if (hdnAddrSheetId.Value!=String.Empty)
            {                
                FillAddressDetails();  //load values on edit mode              

            }            

        }
    }
 public void FillAddressDetails()
    {
        string addrShtId = "" + Request.QueryString["addrshtid"];

        AddrShtBOL objBOL = new AddrShtBOL();
        AddrShtBAL objBAL = new AddrShtBAL();

        objBOL = objBAL.SelectAddressSheetByID(Util.ToInt(addrShtId));
        // the following 2 text boxes retain the values
        txtHzntalPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtHpos.ToString();
        txtVertPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtVpos.ToString();
        ddlOrientation.SelectedValue = objBOL.AddrshtOrient;
        ddlUnitOfMeasure.SelectedValue = objBOL.AddrshtPosUnits;
        txtLogoHzntalPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtLogoHpos.ToString();
        txtLogoVertPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtLogoVpos.ToString();
        txtLogoName.Text = objBOL.AddrshtLogoNm;
        txtAddr1.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn1;
        txtAddr2.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn2;
        txtAddr3.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn3;
        txtAddr4.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn4;
        txtAddr5.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn5;
        txtAddr6.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnAddrIn6;
        txtRtnAddHzntalPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnShtHpos.ToString();
        txtRtnAddVertPostn.Text = objBOL.AddrshtRetnShtVpos.ToString();      

    }
 //Button click event 
 protected void btnSaveAddSheets_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtHzntalPostn.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            ShowMessage("Please enter Horizontal Position");
            txtHzntalPostn.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (txtVertPostn.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            ShowMessage("Please enter Vertical Position");
            txtVertPostn.Focus();
            return;
        }

        AddrShtBOL BOL = new AddrShtBOL();
        AddrShtBAL BAL = new AddrShtBAL();
        string clientNo = "" + Request.QueryString["clientno"];

        BOL.OmAddrShtId = Util.ToInt(hdnAddrSheetId.Value);

        if (BOL.OmAddrShtId > 0)
        {
            BOL.Action = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            BOL.Action = 1;
        }
        BOL.ClientNo = clientNo;
        BOL.AddrShtFmtCd = 0;// addrShtFmtCd;
        BOL.AddrshtHpos = Util.ToDecimal(txtHzntalPostn.Text.Trim());
        BOL.AddrshtVpos = Util.ToDecimal(txtVertPostn.Text.Trim());
        BOL.AddrshtOrient = ddlOrientation.SelectedValue;
        BOL.AddrshtPosUnits = ddlUnitOfMeasure.SelectedValue;
        BOL.CreatedBy = "" + Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
        int result = BAL.InsertAddressSheet(BOL);

        hdnAddrSheetId.Value = result.ToString();

        if (result > 0)
        {
            lblAddr.Text = "Address Sheet details saved";

            BindAddressSheet();          

        }
        if (BOL.Action == 1)
        {
            hdnAddrSheetId.Value = result.ToString();
            lblErr.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Client Side

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-6">
 <label for="description">
 H. Pos</label>
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtHzntalPostn" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" MaxLength="7"placeholder="0"> </asp:TextBox>                        
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cmp1" runat="server" ErrorMessage=" <= 999.999" ControlToValidate="txtHzntalPostn"Operator="LessThan" Type="Double" ValueToCompare="1000" Style="font-size: 14px;" ValidationGroup="addrsheet">                         </asp:CompareValidator>
   </div>
```

Comment: You need to show some code for reference, We can't imagine what's wrong happening at your end.

Comment: Provide Pageload code and also details of what you have done in Compare validator.

Comment: Please provide actual code, not images.